# NoSQL. Cassandra. Modelling external ids

Tags: python, database-design, cassandra, nosql

We have product like:

```
class Product(Model):
    """
    Base Product Model
    """
    shop_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, required=True)
    product_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, required=True, default=uuid.uuid4)    
    wikimart_id = columns.Integer(index=True) # Convert to user defined type?
    yandex_id = columns.Integer(index=True)
```

Periodically (once a day) we update products from list.

Currently we have to use constructions like

```
if Product.filter(wikimart_id=external_id):
   p = Product.get(shop_id=shop_id, wikimart_id=external_id)
   d['product_id'] = p.product_id # Setting key in dict from which model will be updated
```

Is it ok for Cassandra, or we should think how to create models that will have external_id as primary key for updating products?

Like:

```
class ProductWikimart(Model):
    """
    Wikimart Product Model
    """
    shop_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, required=True)
    wikimart_id = columns.Integer(primary_key=True)
    product_id = columns.UUID(index=True)

class ProductYandex(Model):
    """
    Yandex Product Model
    """
    shop_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, required=True)
    yandex_id = columns.Integer(primary_key=True)
    product_id = columns.UUID(index=True)
```

Which way is more preferable?

**UPD** This question is about generic modelling for NoSQL. Not only about cassandra :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [article](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_compound_keys_c.html) would be helpful for you.

I don't think the product_id is a good candidate for a clustering key due to it relatively frequent changes. So, I think the second version of product model (with ProductWikimart and ProductYandex) would be better. But then you can get new problems: for instance, how to match ProductWikimart and ProductYandex product ids?

Speaking of data modeling for Cassandra in general there is [Model Around Your Queries](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling) rule. So, to tell what kind of table structure would be better we should know how it would be requested.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm also thinking that second approach better for import case. product_id will be matched latter in this case. But "how?" is right question. Keeping in head this solution :)